# Not to call componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, react-component, react-state

I am having problem with react-animated-tree-v2.
I am trying to on item toggle load data.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-animated-tree-v2-forked-586cbt

For now I want when only `<SomeComponentTree\>` is opened then only get data.

But now, when it is toggled `<Tree content="sub-subtree with children">` then child component is again mounted and saved state inside is also lost and it calls data to fetch again.

Is there any chance that I can do that without changing npm package?

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-animated-tree-v2-forked-586cbt checked what is going on here.

Want that component state is still there not component is mounted for new.